# Access Format Excel Row as Short Date (Always reverts to US)

Tags: excel, vba, datetime, ms-access, formatting

I have an annoying issue whereby I have csv files that get saved in a date format I need to change e.g. dd-mmm-yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy.

My sub will work if I enter the file name and path directly in the sub but when I call it as a sub routine and pass the name in as variable string, it always saves the date in a US format e.g. mm/dd/yyyy (where its crosses that issue e.g 01/06/2016 becomes 06/01/2016).

So this works:

```
Sub TEST_openfile()
Dim fmDate As Date

Dim xlApp As Object
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

'Workbook to open
xlApp.workbooks.Open "S:\Data\20160601.csv", , False

'Make sure excel is visible on the screen
xlApp.Visible = True
xlApp.Windows(1).Visible = True

'Define the sheet in the Workbook as XlSheet
Set xlsheet1 = xlApp.Worksheets(1)

'Format date column to short date format
With xlsheet1
    .Columns("A:A").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
End With

Set xlsheet1 = Nothing

'Close workbook save changes (disables alerts as csv always generate save prompt even if you have saved the file).
xlApp.Application.displayalerts = False
xlApp.activeworkbook.Save
xlApp.Quit
xlApp.Application.displayalerts = True
Set xlApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

But if I try to use it in a sub routine like this:

```
Sub Import_multiple_csv_files()
'This is for the funnel detailed report.
'Requires an extra sub routine to open the csv files and format the dates correctly before importing

DoCmd.SetWarnings False

    Const strPath As String = "C:\Data\" 'Directory Path
    Const strPathNew As String = "C:\Data\Loaded\" 'Move files too
    Dim strFile As String 'Filename
    Dim strFileList() As String 'File  Array
    Dim intFile As Integer 'File Number

    'Loop through the folder & build file list
    strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.csv")
    While strFile <> ""
        'add files to the list
        intFile = intFile + 1
        ReDim Preserve strFileList(1 To intFile)
        strFileList(intFile) = strFile
        strFile = Dir()
    Wend
     'see if any files were found
    If intFile = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No Data Files Were Found", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "No Files"
        Exit Sub
    End If
     'cycle through the list of files &  import to Access
    For intFile = 1 To UBound(strFileList)
        'Define variable to pass to sub routine
        strFile = strPath & strFileList(intFile)
        'Call sub routine to open csv file first and format dates
        Call openfile(strFile)
        'Import to db
        DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelimi, "Funnel Import Specification", _
        "Import Data", strPath & strFileList(intFile), True
        'MoveFile
        Name strPath & strFileList(intFile) As strPathNew & strFileList(intFile)
    Next

    Call DeleteImportErrorTables
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "qry_Delete_Total", acViewNormal, acEdit
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    MsgBox UBound(strFileList) & " file(s) imported", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Data Imported"

DoCmd.SetWarnings True

End Sub
```

With the sub routine as:

```
Sub openfile(strFile As String)
Dim fmDate As Date

Dim xlApp As Object
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

'Workbook to open
xlApp.workbooks.Open strFile, , False

'Make sure excel is visible on the screen
xlApp.Visible = True
xlApp.Windows(1).Visible = True

'Define the sheet in the Workbook as XlSheet
Set xlsheet1 = xlApp.Worksheets(1)

'Format date column to short date format
With xlsheet1
    .Columns("A:A").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
End With

Set xlsheet1 = Nothing

'Close workbook save changes (disables alerts as csv always generate save prompt even if you have saved the file).
xlApp.Application.displayalerts = False
xlApp.activeworkbook.Save
xlApp.Quit
xlApp.Application.displayalerts = True
Set xlApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

So the first sub works fine when run alone and declaring the file and path within it.

But the 2nd code and the sub routine thats called, always makes the date revert to US format and its driving me insane.

I did try the format "m/d/yyyy" as is recorded in an excel macro when changing the column format. I believe the regional settings are then meant to revert the date to the local setting. This doesnt work :(

Any suggestions would be great thank you.

Comment: But you specify: `.Columns("A:A").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"` so why do you expect another format?

Comment: That was me trying diferent variations. And this is what you get if you record a macro in Excel when converting a row or cell to shortdate no matter what regional setting your machine is at. The MS default.

Comment: But if you wish another format, then adjust the date format.

Comment: Yep tried that but didnt make a diference when used in a subroutine, but I think I have narrowed the issue down to if I make excel visible or not so just trying a few tests.